# Find out caller function in Angular2, Typescript

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to find out the caller function of a particular function in my angular2/ionic2 project..
No luck with

```
arguments.callee.caller.toString()
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do on a more abstract scale?

Comment: I'm building a logger for my app and I want to log the caller function..

Comment: I'm trying to do the same. There seems to be no way to do this. Especially if after the "transpilation" of 'use strict'... I would be curious as to how this could be done. I'm stomped have been looking for a solution for days

Comment: can you share some code ?

Answer (score 13):

I know this is a bit late, but I just had the same problem and hopefully this will help someone else.

You can produce a stack trace by doing

```
console.log((new Error).stack);
```

That will show you which function called your particular function

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check Call Stack in your browser dev tools. Take for example [Chrome Dev Tools Stack Trace](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#call-stack)